# How to right-to-left emails are right-aligned?

Tags: 8, users, emails

In my Drupal 8 site, I am using Arabic email for sign up, log in, forgot password. I get Arabic email content, however, the email content is left aligned. I am using PHP Mailer on my site for sending emails. When I tried with Mail Systems + Mime Mail + SMTP, then I get an error like "reply-to" is not set. Is it possible to align Arabic email content from right to left using PHPMailer?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Mime Mail or HTML Mail module to enable HTML emails in your Drupal instance.
Then, through configuration translation, you can add `dir="rtl"` to the container enclosing your Arabic email message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Am trying with the option.When i have send a test email,then  showing "reply-to" email not to set.How can i solve this?

Comment: Which module did you use? How are you sending the test email?

Comment: Am using Mail system+HTML mail.In "config/system/htmlmail/test" we can sent the test mail.I have also tried with Mimemail+Mail system+SMTP the same  error have shown.

Comment: Am using Mail system+HTML mail.In "config/system/htmlmail/test" we can sent the test mail.I have also tried with Mimemail+Mail system+SMTP the same  error have shown.

Comment: This might be a specific error with your mail service provider.

Comment: But smtp +PHP mailer sending emails correctly.But right alignment option is not possible.We cant set dir = "rtl" from backend.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas

Comment: I am using html mailer now.Where we have the settings in Configuration Translation page for dir=rtl?